# I want to create a plot with Strings on the y-Axis and multiple Lines

Tags: r, string, ggplot2

I am working on a secondary structure Analysis using the dssp Programm.
It creates a Vector with different Strings, which can be interpreted as Secondary Structures.

eg.: " " ," ", "S", "H", "H", "H", "H", " ", "S", " ", "T", "T", " ", " ", "S"," "

I did a dssp Analysis for different Frames of my MD-Simulation and now want to show what kind of Secondary Structure each Residue belongs to in a certain Frame ( according to dssp).

[image: This is a Paint image how it should look]

I already have a Data Frame which contains the Information ( Columns are named after the Residue, Rows after Frames)
e.g.

```
           Res1 Res2 Res3 Res4
 Frame 1      H   T     B   "" 

 Frame 1001   H   H     S   ""

 Frame 2001   H   H     S   ""
```

English is not my native language so i find it kind of hard to find the right words to get help from a search engine.

I think it should be possible with ggplot2 but i am a bloody beginner in R and ggplot2

Answer (score 0):

From your data, as `dat`. First we need to rearrange it:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- dat %>% add_rownames("row") %>%
               gather(var, val, -row)
```

Your data should now look like:

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 3]

          row    var   val
        (chr) (fctr) (chr)
1     Frame 1   Res1     H
2  Frame 1001   Res1     H
3  Frame 2001   Res1     H
4     Frame 1   Res2     T
5  Frame 1001   Res2     H
6  Frame 2001   Res2     H
7     Frame 1   Res3     B
8  Frame 1001   Res3     S
9  Frame 2001   Res3     S
10    Frame 1   Res4    NA
11 Frame 1001   Res4    NA
12 Frame 2001   Res4    NA
```

Now we can plot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(row), y = factor(val), group = var, col = var)) + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]

You'll probably want to manually order the factors for `val`, you can change the order in the `levels` argument. After this rerun the plot command without the `factor` around `val`:

```
dat$val <- factor(dat$val, levels = c(NA, "S", "B", "H", "T"))
```

Comment: you are a genius and a lifesaver :D
thank you very much :)

Comment: Can i ask you another Question?
My full graph will have 9-17 lines. The Problem is, that mutiple lines are Parallel to each other, which makes it almost impossible to see most of them.
is there a way to avoid that Problem (like having the lines displayed slightly shifted to each other)?